# Child data field aggregated into one comma separated field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working in SQL Server 2008 R2

I have a parent table and a child table (one to many relationship). What I would like to do is query the parent table but also include a field from the child table aggregated into a comma separated string.

So if the parent table is called Person with an ID field, FirstName and LastName and the child table is called Kids with and ID field, a ParentID field (FK to the parent table), FirstName, and LastName...I would like to return a dataset similar to this:

ParentFirstName = Mike

ParentLastName = Davis

KidsFirstNames = Suzy, David, Alex

I thought there was a way to do this with the For XML Path but I cannot remember the syntax.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this example

```
declare @YourTable table (BirthDay datetime, PersonName varchar(20)) 
insert into @YourTable VALUES ('1-10-2010',     'Joe'  ) 
insert into @YourTable VALUES ('2-10-2010',     'Bob'  ) 
insert into @YourTable VALUES ('2-10-2010',     'Alice') 



SELECT 
    p1.BirthDay 
        ,STUFF( 
                   (SELECT 
                        ', ' + p2.PersonName 
                        FROM @YourTable p2 
                        WHERE p2.BirthDay=p1.BirthDay 
                        ORDER BY p2.PersonName 
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE 
                   ).value('.','varchar(max)') 
                   ,1,2, '' 
              ) AS PersonNames 
    FROM @YourTable p1 
    GROUP BY p1.BirthDay
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, astander. I understand everything going on except the following portion: TYPE 
                   ).value('.','varchar(max)')  Could you explain what is going on there? Thanks, again...this is great!